# Java Generic method call result in compilation error

Tags: java, validation, generics

Everything was fine with below code, until making a call. How could I the issue without explicit casting? Thanks in advance.

The validator interface

```
 public interface Validator <T extends GenericRequest>{
     String validate(T request);
 }
```

The validator implementing classes

```
public class AccountOpeningRequestValidator implements Validator<AccountOpeningRequest> {

public class AccountTerminationRequestValidator implements Validator<AccountTerminationRequest> {
```

The validation service

```
public class ValidationService {

    private static final Map<Class<?>, Validator<? extends GenericRequest>> map = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        map.put(AccountOpeningRequest.class, new AccountOpeningRequestValidator());
        map.put(AccountTerminationRequest.class, new AccountTerminationRequestValidator());
    }

    public static <T extends GenericRequest> String validate(T request) {
        // !!! This does not work !!!!
        return map.get(request.getClass()).validate(request));
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need to use generics like that? Can't you have an abstract 'validate' method on the GenericRequest class?

Comment: And if it's fine until you make the call, that's not a compilation error. It's a runtime error.

Comment: I want to keep the pojo clean.

Comment: The error is "The method validate(capture#5-of ? extends GenericRequest) in the type Validator<capture#5-of ? extends GenericRequest> is not applicable for the arguments (T"

Comment: No, I mean compilation error happened on this line - "return map.get(request.getClass()).validate(request));"

Answer (score 0):

Of course it would not work. The java compiler cannot be sure that in your map every value has the same generic parameter as the class specified in the corresponding key. *You are* sure, but compiler is not. You can insist on this via unchecked cast:

```
@SuppressWarning("unchecked")
Validator<T> validator = (Validator<T>)map.get(request.getClass());
return validator.validate(request));
```

This way you explicitly say to compiler "I know better, this cast will always work" and compiler thinks like "Ok, I will compile it. If you have a runtime exception after that, it's not my fault".